# Malloc and free in loop in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

Is it always necessary to match malloc() and free() calls? I have to allocate dynamic memory for structure and then free it after some operations. Can I overwrite the data in dynamic memory or I should free them first and malloc again? For examples:

```
int x =5,len = 100;

do{
    struct test *test_p = (struct test *) malloc(sizeof(struct test) + len);

 /* ---do some operation ----------  */

    free(test_p);
    x--;
}while(x);
```

Another approach is to do malloc before loop and do free() inside loop. Can i use this struct pointer after freeing it ? For Example:

```
int x =5, len = 100;
struct test *test_p = (struct test *) malloc(sizeof(struct test) + len);

do{

 /* ---do some operation ----------  */

    free(test_p);
    x--;
}while(x);
```

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to release all allocated memory when you don't need it anymore. **When you don't need it anymore.** You don't have to allocate and release the same buffer every iteration of your loop, you can simply allocate it before the loop and release it after.

Comment: No, you can't use memory after freeing it. You also can't free it more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is using a flex-array approach and your allocation makes sense, you could reuse your memory during each iteration. This will save you a lot of time on allocating and freeing.

```
int x =5,len = 100;

struct test* test_p = malloc(sizeof *test_p + len);
do {
    // do some operation using test_p
    x--;
} while(x);
free(test_p);
```

If you want to "clear" your structure at each iteration, you can do so with a compound literal at the start of your loop.

```
do {
    *test_p = (struct test){0};
```

and [there are better ways to malloc](https://makecleanandmake.com/2014/07/26/how-to-malloc-the-right-way/)

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I want to perform some operation on structures members. After each loop, I need to change members values (includes some char pointers). So is it okay to overwrite this?

Comment: @ronme026 yes or no, depending on what you mean with char pointers, if you feel your original code doesn't demonstrate enough for us to provide adequate answers, please update it.

Comment: Sure. I got your point. I will probably go with your first solution. Allocate enough memory and free it outside of a loop. Inside loop, i can overwrite the members, right?

Comment: @ronme026 if I understand your question correctly, yes. Though if you could shed some light on why you are doing `malloc(sizeof(struct test) + len)` I could help more. Why the `+len` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to free an object when you no longer need it. In your situation, if you are using the `test` struct in each iteration of the `while` loop, I would write the code as follows:

```
int x =5,len = 100;
struct test *test_p = (struct test *) malloc(sizeof(struct test) + len);
do{
    /* ---do some operation ----------  */

    x--;
}while(x);
free(test_p);
```

Comment: Thanks @peter for reply.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
int x =5, len = 100;
struct test *test_p = (struct test *) malloc(sizeof(struct test) + len);

do{

 /* ---do some operation ----------  */

    free(test_p);
    x--;
}while(x);
```

After calling `free(test_p);`, you shouldn't use `test_p` again. It means the `test_p` only be valid in the **first** time of loop.

Comment: Thanks @Nan. I see, I can not use this pointer after I free it.